# Can't find sqlite db in folder, I feel stupid [Windows Phone 8]

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8

I'm having so much trouble with a simple project. My WP8 app needs to retrive data from an SQLite db, so I put its file in the Assets folder (it's  a temporary thing) and I need to get it. It won't. This is my code.

```
try
  {
    string path="\\Assets\\dbelli.db";
    public SQLiteConnection conn=new SQLiteConnection(path);
  }
catch (Exception e)
  {
       MessageBox.Show("Error: " + e.ToString());
  }
```

Which throws a `FileNotFoundException`. 
I've searched everything on the web, and I even tried to put the absolute path from `C:\`, but it won't work. I feel so stupid for this. Can I ask for help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
string DB_PATH = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Your local path here");
```

and then

```
_connection = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH)
```

You can get bit of a help [here](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_use_SQLite_in_Windows_Phone)

Comment: Turned out I wasn't implementing the right libraries. But it still doesn't find the db, it creates a new one, so any eventual query after estabilishing the connection doesn't work, because it cannot find the tables. How can I add the sqlite file to the project correctly? I've already set "Build Action"=Embedded Resource and Copy Always

Comment: If your file is "/Assets/debelli.db", Use:
`string DB_PATH = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "/Assets/debelli.db");`
I have not tested it, but it should work